# Python pandas checking if dataframe contains a certain string

Tags: python, string, pandas, contains

The situation is as follows. I have two dataframes, df A and df B. 
They both contain columns with the column names ['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'].
I basically want to check if a persons full name from df A exists in df B. More abstractly, with some pseudo like code:

```
If (dfA['firstname'][i]+dfA['middlename'][i]+dfA['lastname']) exists in dfB:
     do stuff
else:
     do stuff
```

What's a good and efficient way to do this?
I've come across the .str.match() function, but without any progress.

Thank you in advance for you answers!

Comment: If you inner join both the dataframes dfA and dfB on columns 'firstname', 'middlename' and 'lastname', you get all the rows where a persons full name exists in dfB.

Answer (score 0):

You can using this as your condition (`isin`)

```
dfB[['firstname','middlename','lastname']].sum(1).isin(dfA[['firstname','middlename','lastname']].sum(1))
```